# Share Eclipse Settings With Team

Tags: eclipse

We have a very common use case: we want to standardize all our Eclipse settings like formatter, warnings, save actions etc.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578069/eclipse-how-to-share-java-compiler-errors-warnings-settings-across-entire-team) got the answer to just use project settings for that, but here's why that won't work for us:

**We have way too many projects.** We have about 500 Maven / Tycho reactors (many with branches) which in turn contain of usually 3-5 Java projects. Copying project settings for all of these is tedious, error prone and not update-friendly.

So we decided to import workspace setting for each workspace, but that's not optimal either. E.g. I already have about 100 workspaces, so it's almost as tedious and error prone as the project settings.

Let's not even talk about the fact that most of us have more then one Eclipse installation.

Right now I'm thinking about creating a custom plug-in / fragment for Eclipse, which programmatically adds our company's formatter and other settings to the workspace. It would only need to be installed once, and could be updated via the built-in update mechanism.

But I really can't believe nobody has a similiar problem. So I wondering, if there is a build-in way to share Eclipse settings with a big team with many projects?

Comment: This might be something you can do with the Oomph project at Eclipse, but I haven't dug into it myself.

Comment: @nitind Isn't Oomph just to create templates for Eclipse instances? I'm not particularly worried about the Eclipse installation, but more about the workspace settings. (Also I'm not sure if Oomph is allowed for companies in Europe any longer.)

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse Oomph](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.oomph) is licensed under [EPL 1.0](https://projects.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-public-license-1.0) - I can't see why that shouldn't be allowed for companies.

Wrt https://stackoverflow.com/a/37799711/10235188 also [Yatta Profiles for Eclipse](https://www.yatta.de/profiles/help#collapse-01-07) is mentioned to share Eclipse preferences like Code Formatter and other settings.

Comment: I was referring to the [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) which forbids companies from storing company data on external servers (except if the servers comply with the GDPR).

Comment: That's weird...GDPR must regulate only personal data or stuff related to people, I don't think that storing the IDE settings would break the law...
If you can store the settings on a repository, then you will be able to double check contents manually, in order to find gdpr offending content